# What happens with close voting when there is no winning reason?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons

What happens with a question if it has >= 5 close votes, but no winning close reason, i.e. there is a tie to the top reason?

Mathematically, this is only possible when there are no more than 2 votes for a particular reason.

Does it stay in the close queue until some vote reason gets 3 votes (or 2 in the unlikely case of all-1 ties)?

Comment: See [What happens if a fifth person chooses a different reason to close?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32700/164403) on the über-meta.

Comment: Thanks, it's indeed a duplicate.